# Why do we define cosets of the kernel this way?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

My book defines cosets of kernel of a homomorphim $\phi$ as $$ aH = Ha = \{ x \in G: \phi(x) = \phi(a)\}.$$

When I tried to define the coset myself before looking at the proof, I defined it as

$$aH = \{ ax \in G: \phi(ax) = \phi(a)\phi(x) = e' \} = \{ ax \in G : \phi(x) = \phi(a^{-1})\}. $$

After looking at the proof, I found that if I do it my way, I would get $x = ha^{-1}$ so that $x$ does not belong to any coset. I am wondering what was my mistake?

Comment: You've defined $aH$ to be the set of things that look like $ax$ which $\phi$ sends to the identity... everything in $G$ looks like $ax$, so really you're defining it to be the set of things in $G$ that $\phi$ sends to the identity, which is just the kernel $H$ itself, not $aH$.

Comment: Your actual error is the equation $\phi(a) \phi(x) = e'$. Instead this should be $\phi(a) \phi(x) = \phi(a) e' = \phi(a)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *definition* of the coset is the standard $$aH:=\{ax:x\in H\}$$ Now we have $$y=ax\in aH\implies \phi(x)=e'\implies \phi(ax)=\phi(a)\phi(x)=\phi(a)$$ so $\phi(y)=\phi(a)$. Conversely, if $\phi(y)=\phi(a)$ then $$\phi(y)\phi(a)^{-1}=e'\implies \phi(ya^{-1})=e'\implies ya^{-1}\in H\implies y=ax$$ for some $x\in H$ and therefore $y\in aH$.

Hence $y\in aH$ if and only if $\phi(y)=\phi(a)$ and we are done.

Comment: The first line was helpful. The other stuff didn't really answer my question.

Comment: @sidht The first line gives the actual definition of cosets (in general). I then show that an equivalent definition is given by that in your book. Your definition does not really make sense, see comment from sea turtles. If you were going to "guess" a definition, I think the one I give in the first line would be the most natural choice, given that it _is_ the definition. Your book's is an equivalent reformulation.